# How to bind objects out array 1 from layer deeper

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I would like to build a poker dex where I can see all the information about all the pokemons. Now I use the pokedex api https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3 and I want to have a list of all his stats with a pokemon. The json I get is split into 2 objects

```
stats": [

    {
        "base_stat": 80,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
            "name": "speed",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"
        }
    },
    {
        "base_stat": 100,
        "effort": 1,
        "stat": {
            "name": "special-defense",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/"
        }
    },
    ......
]
```

In this way it is not automatically linked to 1 object like:

```
stats": [

    {
        "base_stat": 80,
        "effort": 0,
        "name": "speed",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"
    },
    {
        "base_stat": 100,
        "effort": 1,
        "name": "special-defense",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/"
    },
    ......
]
```

How can i do this?
I tried this, and this works but it doesn't seem like the solution.

```
public class Type {
    private PType type;
    private int base_stat;
    private int effort;

    public Type(PType type, int base_stat, int effort){this.type = type; this.base_stat = base_stat; this.effort = effort;}

    public class PType{
        private String name;
        public String getName() {return this.name;}
    }

    //getters&setters
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `TypeAdapter` ([javadocs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)).

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String inputJson = "{\"base_stat\": 80,...}";
      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Stats.class, new StatsTypeAdapter()).create();
      Stats stats = gson.fromJson(inputJson, Stats.class);
    }

    class Stats {
      private int baseStat;
      private int effort;
      private String name;
      private String url;

      // getters/setters
    }

    public class StatsTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Stats> {

      private static final JsonParser PARSER = new JsonParser();
      private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().create();

      @Override
      public void write(JsonWriter out, Stats value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
          out.nullValue();
        } else {
          JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
          // convert back to JSON...
          out.jsonValue(GSON.toJson(json));
        }
      }

      @Override
      public Stats read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        JsonObject json = PARSER.parse(in).getAsJsonObject();
        Stats stat = new Stats();
        stat.setBaseStat(json.get("base_effort").getAsInt());
        stat.setEffort(json.get("effort").getAsInt());
        JsonObject statJson = json.getAsJsonObject("stat");
        stat.setName(statJson.get("name").getAsString());
        stat.setUrl(statJson.get("url").getAsString());
      }
    }
```